# Can I use zoho mail with domain name@example.com without web server

Tags: domains, mail, zoho

I have a domain at example.com
I have zoho mail account for this domain.

Is it possible to receive emails in my zoho account without having hosting?

Comment: You need a mail server to get mail.   It sounds like you want Zoho to be that mail server.   I assume you mean that you don't have a *web* server.  I've edited your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have DNS associated with your domain name you follow the instructions here https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/email-hosting-with-zoho.html in particular, Step 3 `Configure the MX records of your domain to point to Zoho Mail Servers, to start receiving emails to your domain accounts in Zoho.`